# Android/Java - Random Read line not changing

Tags: java, android, file-io

My text file contains a known number of lines (the first line of the file is the number of lines). I want to randomly read a line from the file - to do this I use `LineNumberReader`. The problem is, that it doesn't generate a new string - the random number changes but the string it gets from the `LineNumberReader` doesn't.

As the title implies this is an Android app. `textbox` is the output area, `testbox` is for debugging (in this code it displays the random number - to check that it has changed) and `r` is a `Random`

This sample code is the `onClick` for the only button in the app.

```
           String fileName = "\\sdcard\\Q's.txt";
   try {
       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
               new InputStreamReader(
                       new DataInputStream(
                               new FileInputStream(fileName))));

       // Get the number of lines in the text file
       numLines = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine().toString().trim());

       // get a random number and write it to the test text box
       int rnd = r.nextInt(numLines);
       String tmp = Integer.toString(rnd);
       testBox.setText(tmp);

       // get random number - go to line - save in String "text"
       LineNumberReader rdr = new LineNumberReader(br);
       rdr.setLineNumber(r.nextInt(numLines));
       textBox.setText(rdr.readLine());

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        textBox.setText("FileNotFound");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        textBox.setText("IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe){
        textBox.setText("Number Formated Wrong");
    } finally {}
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried closing and reseting  `br` and `rdr`and can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line number doesn't affect what *line* gets returned, just the line number that will be reported for it.

The whole point of a `LineNumberReader` is not to automatically seek to a specific line, it's to keep track of the current line number without you having to worry about it.

In other words, you just open the reader and start reading. When you find a line of interest, you can call `getLineNumber()` to find out what line it was.

To that end, `setLineNumber()` simply changes the reported line number for the current line. It does *not* move the file pointer to that line in the file.

To get a specific line `rnd`, the simplest solution is simply to read `rnd` lines in a loop. The last one read is the one you want. In pseudo-code:

```
open bufferedreader br
get limit from first line of br
set rnd to number from 1 to limit
while limit > 0:
    set line to next line of br
    decrement limit
use line
```

If, or when, that turns out to be too inefficient for you, then you can start thinking about pre-loading the data into a memory structure of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

From the Javadoc for [LineNumberReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/LineNumberReader.html#setLineNumber%28int%29):

> Note however, that setLineNumber(int) does not actually change the current position in the stream; it only changes the value that will be returned by getLineNumber().

This class doesn't give you the feature you want it to. Sounds like you'll need to handle this yourself - read the file contents into some sort of structure (perhaps a `Map<Integer, String>` of line number to line contents) and parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Read the number of lines in the file. Pick a random number `n` that's no bigger than this. Read and discard `n-1` lines. Return the next line you read.